# Extra row on Bootstrap navigation bar

Tags: html, django, frontend

My navigation bar is added an extra row and I have no idea why. My navigation bar has two sides: left and right. Left side contains 3 labels, one of them is a dropdown menu. The right side has two labels and the first label always adds another row.

Here is my code, I'm using Django + Bootstrap 3.3.7, jquery 1.12.0.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="topNavBar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <span class="caret"></span>&nbsp Looking for...
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="{% url 'service:room' %}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp Rooms
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="{% url 'service:book' %}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp Textbooks
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="{% url 'service:restaurant' %}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp Restaurants
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="{% url 'service:tutor' %}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp Tutoring
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="{% url 'service:result' %}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp Searching
            <a>
        </li>
    </ul>               
    <!-- </ul> -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        {% block addbar %}
        {% endblock %}
        <!-- <li class="">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp Add Room
            </a>
        </li> -->
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <!-- Link to user's profile -->
        <li class="">
            <a href="{% url 'service:personal-rooms' %}">
                <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp hello {{request.user.username}}
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="{% url 'service:logout' %}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp Log Out
            </a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="">
            <a href="{% url 'service:login' %}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp Log In
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="{% url 'service:register' %}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp Register
            </a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

I appreciate any suggestion you guys may have. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

silly mistake you haven't close your anchor tag here
  do this in "Searching"

```
 <a href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp Searching
            </a>
```

Comment: +1 awe thank you very much <3, I have to be more careful next time. Indeed it is a silly mistake, l  feel a bit embarrassing posting this over here. Well you learn something everyday!

Answer (score 0):

You have a `{% block addbar %}{% endblock %}`, is that causing any unexpected behavior?

Comment: No it doesn't. `{% block addbar %}{% endblock %}` is used to show another label in another html template. The problem is the first label after "Searching" jumps to the second row because there is a space that was created above it.